# Is SGD used in machine learning libraries?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

SGD (Stochastic Gradient Descent) is used in most libraries of different programming languages. Is it also used in machine learning libraries?

Comment: Absolutely, it's a very common method implemented for instance in scikit-learn.

Answer (score 2):

**Big yes**.

In fact, gradient descent is one of the fundamental tools used by many supervised learning models.

You can check out a [very nice docs page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html) about how it is used in scikit-learn.